# C: Accessing the ith vararg

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I've searched for the proper syntax to access the ith variable argument in C to no avail.  Is this possible?  I'd like to access, say, the 2nd argument in a variable argument list.

For example:

```
void mySum( int count, ... )
{
    int sum = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        sum += va_arg(args, int);
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum );
 }
```

This accesses each variable argument in turn.  Is there a way to reference the second variable argument directly, or do you have to call va_arg() at least once first?

Comment: `int mySum( int count, int second, ... )` ... va_start(args, second);

Comment: Are you sure about that @fukanchik? `second` isn't a named arg in this case.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer nothing stops you from having as much named arguments as you want before vararg starts

Comment: @fukanchik: The OP specifically wants to know how to randomly access arguments in the `...` part of the argument list.

Comment: @fukanchik and suppose you want the 20th argument? Doesn't that sorta defeat the point of the va function?

Comment: @vjb do you want to access second argument (as per question body) or general access to any argument (as per question title)?

Comment: @WeatherVane suppose that your function has been called with 19 arguments. Which value are you expecting for your 20th argument which you are accessing directly?

Comment: @fukanchik what is unclear about "ith argument"? It's not me accessing directly, it's you. Replacing `...` with specific argument names is not what was asked.

Comment: @WeatherVane it is not mine. it is from the question: Is there a way to reference the second variable argument `directly`, so my point is - if you want to access the second argument directly then give it a name

Comment: @fukanchik the question is how to access the `ith` argument. Your suggestion has no *general* solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113075/discussion-between-fukanchik-and-weather-vane).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no (good, safe, portable) way to randomly access arguments in a variable argument list. If you know *exactly* how variable argument lists are implemented on your particular platform, you could try to work around the standard `va_*` macros; otherwise, you're stuck with iterating through the list until you reach the argument you want.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Good to know that's pretty much always the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You can't access them randomly because the arguments are stored in stack and you need to know the sizes of all preceding arguments to access a particular one.